# Cocos2d-x Sample HelloCpp not running on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cocos2d-x

I have a problem with the included sample HelloCpp in cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4.

My environment:

- Mac OSX 10.8.2
- cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4
- android-ndk-r8

The proj.ios of the sample is running fine in the xcode emulator but i have problems get the proj.android running on my Android HTC One X Device.
I am able to build the apk file with the makefile from raywenderlich and when i unzip the apk it has the assets/ipad folder included and images in it and after the installation of the apk file on the device the app loads and shows the information about frames etc. in the left lower corner of the screen. But then a notification window pops up and tells me that the program is not able to load "assets/ipad/HelloWorld.png"

The error message is thrown in cocos2dx/platform/android/CCFileUtils.ccp line 134.

Is it correct to load a png file with pData = CCFileUtils::getFileDataFromZip(s_strResourcePath.c_str(), fullPath.c_str(), pSize); ?
Because thats the line where the program is running into in cocos2dx/platform/android/CCFileUtils.ccp line 97.

the value of s_strResourcePath is /data/app/org.cocos2dx.hellocpp.apk and fullpath is assets/ipad/HelloWorld.png.

I really hope someone can help me. Or has the same problem at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out in which folder is you all resources. In my case its in assets/Resources .. So i will setResourceDirectory as "Resources"  so the path will be assets/Resources ...whereas i guess in ur case its ipad
so set it ipad

Add this lines in AppDelegate.cpp->applicationDidFinishLaunching() function. If it's already there then just change it for the android

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID )
        pFileUtil->setResourceDirectory("ipad");
        #endif
```

Try if this works

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Since I use the original sample, in my opinion this functionality is already included in the file [AppDelegate.cpp](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp).

I just wanted to get the sample running. There is not a single line of code written by me. I wonder if this strange behaviour happens only in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your images in "HelloCpp/Resources". Maybe you're adding image files in "HelloCpp/proj.android/assets/".

Try this:
"HelloCpp/Resources/iphone/HelloWorld.png"
"HelloCpp/Resources/ipad/HelloWorld.png"
"HelloCpp/Resources/ipadhd/HelloWorld.png"

Instead of this:
"HelloCpp/proj.android/assets/iphone/HelloWorld.png"
"HelloCpp/proj.android/assets/ipad/HelloWorld.png"
"HelloCpp/proj.android/assets/ipadhd/HelloWorld.png"